# Using ui:repeat to output a ResultSet

Tags: sql-server, jsf, jdbc, jsf-2, resultset

The documentation for the ui:repeat tag in JSF 2.0 says you can iterate over a ResultSet but my code:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.resultSet}" var="row" varStatus="status">
   #{row.string("mySQLColumn")}
</ui:repeat>
```

produces this error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Iteration start index is greater than the number of available rows.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.validateIterationControlValues(UIRepeat.java:682)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:505)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:974)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
```

Comment: This seems to happen at least with empty `ResultSet`. I would expect it not to iterate at all in that case but it throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it seems to be supported as argument for iteration, it would be best to first transform it to a `List` and then iterate.

That way you won't be propagating the database-access technology to the view layer.

Comment: Why does the documentation say the value attribute can contain a ResultSet? http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html

Comment: hm, interesting. It seems it can, but it would be best not to propagate that to the view layer.